# Yii2 GridView Checkbox ajax как принять массив в контролере

Tags: yii2

Нужно отправить в контролер ключи выбранных строк.
Пользователь выбирает нужные чекбоксы в таблице GridView  и данные о ключе отправляются Ajax-ом в контролер. В дебаге вижу, что отправляется массив, но принять не получается

пробовал отправлять так js

```
$(document).ready(function getCart() {
$('#w1 input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var keys = $("#w1").yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    // var keys = $(this).parents('.gridview').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    // var keys = $('#gridview').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    $.ajax({
        url: '../admin/order/create',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {keylist:JSON.stringify(keys)},

        success: function (result) {

            if (!keys) {
                alert('Ошибка');
            }
            // alert(keys);
            console.log(keys);
        },
        // error: function () {
        //     alert('Error!');
        // }
      });

    });
 });
```

и так

```
$(document).ready(function getCart() {
$('#w1 input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var keys = $("#w1").yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    // var keys = $(this).parents('.gridview').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    // var keys = $('#gridview').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    $.ajax({
        url: '../admin/order/create',
        data: {keylist: keys},
        type: 'GET',
        // dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {

            if (!keys) {
                alert('Ошибка');
            }
            // alert(keys);
            console.log(keys);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });

   });
});
```

PHP

```
     namespace app\modules\admin\controllers;

     use app\modules\admin\models\BookSearch;
     use app\modules\admin\models\OrderBook;
     use Yii;
     use app\modules\admin\models\Order;
     use app\modules\admin\models\OrderSearch;
     use app\modules\admin\controllers\AppAdminController;
     use yii\helpers\Json;
     use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
     use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

public function actionCreate()
{

    $model = new Order();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
          $key_list = Yii::$app->request->post('keylist');
          return var_dump($key_list);
    }

  

 //   if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

   //     $id = Yii::$app->request->post('keylist');
   //     echo 'OK';
   //     die();
   //             
        
    $searchModel = new BookSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('create', [

        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
        'id' => $id,
    ]);
   }
```

post

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

get

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите пожалуйста очень нужно принять в контроллере этот массив с ключами.

Comment: а что на сервере написано? что значит не полукчается принять?

Comment: Отправляю в тот же контролер откуда рендерится таблица, пробовал проверки через if (isAjax(), load() !empty()) и ни ошибок ничего, var_dump в контролере и в виде и 0 результата.

Comment: Покажите серверную часть в вопросе

Comment: в этом виде находится создание заказа со стандартной формой _form, заказ создается нормально

Comment: ой, я не сразу увидел, на ECHO в проверке is Ajax он все таки ругнулся Headers already sent. значит я не правильно присваиваю переменной этот массив, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно обработать этот реквест и получить массив

Comment: `$key_list = Yii::$app->request->post('keylist'); $params = $key_list->bodyParams;`  Тут странно `$key_list` будет ваш массив или `null`, у него не может быть `bodyParams`